# Why does only one class member load from NSKeyedUnarchiver and why does my superclass required init never called?

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

Using NSObject and NSCode I can't seem to unarchive more than one member of my class. The class looks like this:
    import Foundation
    import os.log

```
class myObject:NSObject,NSCoding {
var type:String
var color:String = "White"
static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory,in: .userDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL =DocumentsDirectory.appendingPath("myObjects")

struct PropertyKey {
  static let type = "type"
  static let color = "color"
}
init(objType:String) {
  self.type = objType)
}
func encode(with aCoder:NSCoder) {
  aCoder.encode(type,forKey:PropertyKey.type)
  aCoder.encode(color,forKey:PropertyKey.color)
}
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  print("LOADING object")
  guard let myType = (aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.type) as? String?)!
  else {
    os_log("!!! object class unable to decode type.",log:OSLog.default,type: .debug)
    return nil
  }
  self.init(objType: myType)
  color = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.color) as! String
}
```

And I have a ViewController with a viewDidLoad that looks like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  let thisObject = loadObject()
  print("My object has type: \(String(describing: thisObject?.type))")
  print("My object has color: \(String(describing: thisObject?.color))")
}
private func loadObject() -> myObject? {
  print("TRYING to LOAD")
  return (NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: myObject.ArchiveURL.path) as? myObject)
}
```

And the output I get from this is 
TRYING to LOAD
My object has type: theTypeIgave
My object has color: White

Two things strike me as weird. 1. I can get different types when I run and save different types but the color is always White even if I saved Blue or Red last time I ran the program. 2. I never get the print statement to output anything in the required convenience init? function, so does that init ever get called?

Comment: You should be using `Codable`.

Comment: Can you use Codable on a class object? I thought it was only for Structures...

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: From what I can tell in using Codable, the JSONDecoder.decode call requires a specified data construct to tell it what it is decoding. (It is the second argument in the decode call.) This is problematic for me as I am trying to decode into a superclass where I encoded a subclass of the superclass. So I don't know which data structure to specify for my decode call.

Comment: still not working with Codable and a single struct that I built. Do you have to encode and decode JSONs in the same viewcontroller maybe?

Comment: Made some progress. I put a do-catch around the try in the decoding portion of the JSON call. The error I get is:
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 179."